# How should I be setting automatic dimensions for tableview.tableHeaderView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom header that I am using at the top of my table header that contains a UIImageView that has a defined height and a label with a welcome message for users that will change over time, and also includes the user's company name in it as well.  The view is setup using autolayout, the imageview has a fixed height the label's height is variable and should be able to expand.

When I setup my header with an explicit frame set, the header is displayed as expected.  When I intentionally add a long string of text to the label the frame does not change (expected).

When I remove the explicit frame and instantiate the view with just an init, the height of the header is the height of the view in the xib file.  Depending on how I stretch the xib prior to building the app, this can be either too big, or too small.

After instantiating the view and setting up the custom message, I am assigning it to the tableHeaderView using `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;`

How should I be setting my frame so it would be dynamic in the same way I would use `self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;` for a section header?